# laravel update function updates all except 1

Tags: function, laravel

So i came across a bug in my application. When i want to update an project everything updates smoothly. Except one input. the `projectnaam` won't change. In the flashdata I send after success shows the changed projectnaam but after i check the database everything is changed except `projectnaam`

My code :

```
public function updateProject(Request $request){
        $input = $request->input('projectnaam');
        $data = array(
            'titel'  => $request['titel'],
            'status'     => $request['status'],
            'prioriteit'  => $request['prioriteit'],
            'soort'   => $request['soort'],
            'projectnaam'  => $request['projectnaam'],
            'projecturl'  => $request['projecturl'],
            'gebruikersnaam'  => $request['gebruikersnaam'],
            'wachtwoord' => bcrypt($request['wachtwoord']),
            'omschrijvingproject' => $request['omschrijvingproject'],
        );
        Project::where('projectnaam', '=', $input)->update($data);
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Project '. $request['projectnaam']. ' veranderd.');
        return redirect('/projectmuteren');
    }
```

I hope anyone of you sees my mistake :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include  `'projectnaam'`  in your `$fillable` array in class `Project`

Comment: yup i did that aswel..

protected $fillable = ['titel',
        'status',
        'prioriteit',
        'soort',
        'projectnaam',
        'projecturl',
        'gebruikersnaam',
        'wachtwoord',
        'telefoonnummer',
        'omschrijvingproject',
        'gebruiker_id',
    ];

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating `projectnaam` in your code because there is nothing to update. I'll take out 3 lines of code from your example for brevity's sake.

```
$input = $request->input('projectnaam');

'projectnaam'  => $request['projectnaam'],

Project::where('projectnaam', '=', $input)->update($data);
```

`$request->input('projectnaam');` is the same thing as `$request['projectnaam']`. Therefore, `$input` is also equal to `$request['projectnaam']`.

In other words, you are looking for the Project based on the provided `projectnaam` value. Then you are "updating" it with that exact same value so there is nothing to update. The two are one and the same.

To put things more concretely, lets assign it a value of 1. You are searching for Project where `projectnaam` is equal to 1 and then "updating" it with the value of 1 so naturally, there is nothing to update.

Comment: ahhhh.. and do you maybe know any other fix for this so i can still check for the input and update it..

Comment: Because it now only updates when the $input is exactly the same as the one changing and it had to be like so i changed the where to make it work. still thanks for your reply and it helped me towards the answer!

Comment: IMO you should not update with where(), you should use find() or first() to bring back a single object.